# web scraping through json data in ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, screen-scraping

I want to do web scraping from one site and data is coming in json

```
{
"html" : "<div id='price'> Price $4 </div> "
}
```

can i scraping this data or parsing in html and then scrape it through html selector in ruby rails

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can try Nokogiri gem.

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML("<div id='price'> Price $4 </div> ")
html.css("#price").text # Price $4
```